# Enums - All options value

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, flags

Is there a way to add an "All values" option to an enum without having to change its value every time a new value is added to the enum?

```
[Flags] 
public enum SomeEnum
{
    SomeValue =  1,
    SomeValue2 = 1 << 1,
    SomeValue3 = 1 << 2,
    SomeValue4 = 1 << 3,
    All = ?
}
```

Update:

Ended up inheriting from long and using `long.MaxValue` for All option.

Comment: -1 will make me do a special treatment for that value and I wont be able to use HasFlag method.

Comment: you are generally testing `[Flags]` enums for discrete bits anyway - in which case it should work absolutely fine.

Comment: Actually I want an "All option" that HasFlag will return true no matter which option I test.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since you should define the empty value in a `Flags enum such as` None = 0`, the simplest way of defining the` All`value is by simply inverting all the bits in`None`.

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
   None = 0,
   A = 1,
   B = 2,
   C = 4,
   ...
   All = ~None
}
```

Note that `~0` instead of `~None` will not work for unsigned backing types as that is -1, which is not a valid value for unsigned.

*Edit: Answer was modified to use an inverted None instead of an explicit constant such as 0x7FFFFFFF or ~0, as this also works for unsigned*

Comment: ah, ninja edit to add an extra FF renders my comment obsolete ;p

Comment: You can also set the value of the `All` enumeration to `~0`, which is functionally the same. I just get bamboozled seeing all those `F`'s next to eachother.

Comment: I disagree with `-1`, `0xFFFFFFFF` or `~0` solution. When you assume `All = -1` than `(SomeEnum.SomeValue | SomeEnum.SomeValue2 | SomeEnum.SomeValue3 | SomeEnum.SomeValue4).HasFlag(SomeEnum.All)` is false. Maybe something like `All = (SomeValue4 << 1) - 1` could help

Comment: When I try this I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'."

Comment: I updated the answer to include other integer types.

Comment: Can int.MaxValue be used?

Comment: Yes, int.MaxValue (or uint.MaxValue, or ulong.MaxValue etc.) works.

Comment: I would suggest being more explicit about what "All" means. When debugging in Visual Studio, it could be more useful to see a value of "A | B | C | ..." rather than "-1". Sure, it requires more work to maintain, but you'll thank yourself later when you don't have to ask "What is -1 supposed to represent?"

Answer (score 18):

It should be like this:

```
[Flags] 
public enum SomeEnum
{
    SomeValue =  1,
    SomeValue2 = 1 << 1,
    SomeValue3 = 1 << 2,
    SomeValue4 = 1 << 3,
    All = SomeValue | SomeValue2 | SomeValue3 | SomeValue4
}
```

Comment: I don't disagree, but note the OP is explicitly asking for a maintenance-free option. I kinda agree that explicit is best, though.

Comment: I also like this explicit approach and to solve the maintenance problem I would add a unit test that at least warns the user if a new option is added to the enum and not to the All OR, but there could be another problem: in my case I need to track if the user explicitly selected the All option (= also option added in the future should be considered) or if the user selected all the present options one by one (= option added in the future should not be considered), so I need to use All = ~None because it has a different value.

Answer (score 5):

An enum can be made of many different length integer types (short, int, long). This makes the `#FFFFFFFF` solution inappropriate (as pointed out in @MarcGravell comment).

An enum can be made of unsigned types (uint for isntance). This makes the `-1` solution inappropriate.

My best bet is, maintenance-free:

```
All = ~0
```

Answer (score 3):

The Idea is to use the behavior of the enum to calculate the last value.

Add *Last* field after all 'real' enum values.

Add *All* field equals to `(Last << 1) - 3`.

```
[Flags]
public enum SomeEnum
{
    SomeValue =  1,
    SomeValue2 = 1 << 1,
    SomeValue3 = 1 << 2,
    SomeValue4 = 1 << 3,

    // Do not add values after this
    Last,
    All = (Last << 1) - 3,
}
```

I answered it at: [How to use Enum with aditional options (All, None)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228634/how-to-use-enum-with-aditional-options-all-none/13008365#13008365)

You can check my blog at [Enum Trick](https://ofirzeitoun.wordpress.com/) for more information and ideas.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `All = ((Last - 1) << 1) - 1` ?

Comment: Actually no... assume you have 4 bit flags. `LAST` = `1001` = last flag + 1.  `LAST << 1` = `10010` = *next* flag + 2. Subtract 3 from that and you get next flag - 1 (`10000 - 1` = `1111` in our example), or all actual values.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing built is that will make such an `All` option automatically update when the Enum changes.

You may want to have a special value (monitor value) that means `All` (say -1), even if it is not the bitwise sum of all of the options.

An alternative is to use a value that has all of the bits switched on:

```
All = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: One reason I prefer -1 to 0xFFFFFFFF... now imagine you want to change to `short` or `long`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little trick

```
(SomeEnum)( (1 << ( Enum.GetValues( typeof(SomeEnum) ).Length ) ) -1 )
```

If you added a 'None' Enum name with value = 0 ( `None = 0,` ) then you need to put a '-1' after the Length.

Comment: I like the idea but not the implementation

Comment: Also, you need to put -1 whether you have `None` or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you're okay with a `static readonly` field in a separate type, rather than as a `const` enum field:

```
[Flags] 
public enum SomeEnum
{
    None       = 0,
    SomeValue  = 1,
    SomeValue2 = 1 << 1,
    SomeValue3 = 1 << 2,
    SomeValue4 = 1 << 3,
}

public static class SomeEnumUtility {

    private static readonly SomeEnum[] _someEnumValues = (SomeEnum[])Enum.GetValues( typeof(SomeEnum) );
    public static readonly SomeEnum SomeEnum_All = GetSomeEnumAll();

    // Unfortunately C# does not support "enum generics" otherwise this could be a generic method for any Enum type
    private static SomeEnum GetSomeEnumAll() {

        SomeEnum value = SomeEnum.None; // or `(SomeEnum)0;` if None is undefined.
        foreach(SomeEnum option in _someEnumValues) {
            value |= option;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can get `SomeEnumUtility.SomeEnum_All`. As it's a `static readonly` the computation is only performed once, in a thread-safe manner.

As I wrote in the code-comment, it's unfortunate that C# does not support enum generics, otherwise you could do this:

```
    private static TEnum GetEnumAllFlags<TEnum>() where TEnum : enum {

        TEnum[] allValues = Enum.GetValues<TEnum>();

        TEnum value = (TEnum)0;
        foreach(TEnum option in allValues) {
            value |= option;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Oh well :(

Comment: although it look cool, but it always require the processing of the function. if it's not matter, i rather like the `<EnumBaseType(like int, byte)>.MaxValue`, or the `None` and `All=~None` option

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T EnumSetAll<T>() where T : struct, Enum
  {
    string str = string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)));

    if (Enum.TryParse<T>(str, out var e))
      return e;

    return default;
  }
```